# Send message from popup.js to payload.js

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

**NOTE: THIS IS MY FIRST CHROME EXTENSION AND THIS IS AN EXERCISE TO GET FAMILIAR WITH DEVELOPING EXTENSIONS.**

I am making a chrome extension that parses a page. When the user clicks on the extension button, payload.js executes parsing the page, and in the popup they can select an option that will decide how the parsed info will be outputted.

I want that after they select an option, a function inside of payload.js executes and evaluates the option and formats the parsed information accordingly. Finally, it sends a message back to popup.js containing the formatted parsed info and popup.js displays it in a textbox inside of the popup.

I can communicate from payload.js to popup.js just fine, but cant seem to do the reverse.

Here is my code and what I have tried

popup.js

```
 // Inject the payload.js script into the current tab after the popout has loaded
    window.addEventListener('load', function (evt) {
        chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
            file: 'payload.js'
        });;
    });

// Listen to messages from the payload.js script and write to popout.html
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message) {
    document.getElementById('output').textContent = message;
});

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        var opt = document.getElementById('generate_type');
    opt.addEventListener('click', function() {
            chrome.runtime.sendMessage(opt.value); //contains value of selection
    });
});
```

payload.js

```
console.log("executed");
var parsed_info = [];
parse_info();

function parse_info()
{
  //CODE that parses page
}

function generate_html()
{
  //CODE that generates html output in var html
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage(html);
}

function generate_reddit()
{
  //CODE that generates MARKUP for reddit in var reddit
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage(reddit);
}

function eval_opt(opt)
{
  //evaluate if we should call generate_reddit or generate_html based on opt
}

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message) {
    alert(message);
    eval_opt(opt);
});
```

manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name": "Hello World",
    "description": "A simple page-scraping extension for Chrome",
    "version": "1.0",
    "author": "@Gabriel",

    "background": {
        "scripts": ["popup.js"],
        "persistent": true
    },

    "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "http://*/",
        "https://*/"
    ],
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "logo.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    }
}
```

Comment: In your `popup.js` use `chrome.tabs.sendMessage` instead of `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` and try again.

Comment: ... and specify the tab id as the first parameter ^